Why does findobj behave different in windows than in unix systems?
I am facing something rather curious. I am noticing a behaviour different on the Matlab 2023a function findobj in Windows(10/11) or UNIX (Ubuntu 22).
My issue roots to the search of figures by name. In windows I use the function like this:
figHandle = findobj(groot,'Name',figName);

So providing the figName finds the figure as expected, but running the same command under Matlab 2023a UNIX version it returns empty figHandle. I use the Matlab UNIX version in my CI environment where I found the issue.
Does it rely on lower OS functions that do not behave the same? Can I overcome this issue?

Possibly. MATLAB figure stuff is Java based, but its other stuff in unix, I believe. GTK maybe?

Are you sure the OS is the only difference? Have you tried a mininal code snippet that starts from stratch (clear all, close all, create the figure etc), to make sure that everything is the same except the OS?

I tried this in Matlab Online (R2024a; Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS):
clear all, close all, figName = 'name';  f = figure('Name',figName); figHandle = findobj(groot,'Name',figName)
and it correctly returns the figure handle

@LuisMendo yes I did, I run matlab in batch mode using Matlab2023a and I do close all figures before using the findobj. I cannot use clear all because then I will kill the testing environment
